# Issue while setting up a Neo4J J2EE Project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, neo4j

I tried setting up a very simple J2EE project with neo4j 1.9.4 by following the Neo4J documentation. I've created a very simple class which purpose is to load some data into the graphDB:

```
    package neo4j;

    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
    import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
    import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
    import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
    import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder;
    import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
    import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings;

    public class DBLoader{
       private final String BDD_PATH = "http://localhost:7474/recipeFinderDB";

       public void feedDB() {
        GraphDatabaseBuilder dbBuilder = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
          .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(BDD_PATH);
        GraphDatabaseService db = dbBuilder.newGraphDatabase();

       db.shutdown();
    }
```

I then instantiate this class in a simple jsp file.

But whenever I want to run my project, I get the following error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/RecipeFinder] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 14
>   Stacktrace:] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
>       at neo4j.DBLoader.feedDB(DBLoader.java:20)
>       at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:68)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

This class comes from the neo4j-jernel-1.9.4.jar file, which I've obviously included in my Project's build path. See my classpath below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre7">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v7.0">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/lucene-core-3.6.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-1.9.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo-1.9.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/neo4j-graph-matching-1.9.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/neo4j-jmx-1.9.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/neo4j-kernel-1.9.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/neo4j-lucene-index-1.9.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/neo4j-shell-1.9.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/neo4j-udc-1.9.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jline-0.9.94_1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/scala-library-2.10.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/neo4j/server-api-1.9.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Any help regarding that issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You should check in the war whether the jar is included in the lib folder. I don't know which IDE you are using, there should be some way to specify a runtime dependency, not just compile time. Anyway, you can't use an embedded db with an URL path like that, it requires a file system path, URL paths are for server db.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't added the Neo4j jars to your lib folder.